# Appending InjectionMembers AFTER RegisterType has happened in Unity for .Net

Tags: .net, unity-container

I am using Unity 3.0

I have this code:

```
UnityConfig.Container.RegisterType<IMockProvider, MockProvider>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager(), new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
            new InterceptionBehavior<PerfCounterInterceptor>());
```

Which I believe is just the same as these two statements put together:

```
UnityConfig.Container.RegisterType<IMockProvider, MockProvider>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());

UnityConfig.Container.RegisterType<IMockProvider, MockProvider>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<PerfCounterInterceptor>());
```

What I currently have is a long list of statements like

```
UnityConfig.Container.RegisterType<IMockProvider, MockProvider>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
```

After this long list, I wish to add the same InterceptionBehavior to ALL Registered types, possibly based on certain configuration values.
So, how do I "add the same InterceptionBehavior to ALL Registered types" in some kind of a for loop? I have looked at Container.Registrations, tried using IBuilderContext but to no avail.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`InjectionMember` has a method called `AddPolicies`.  This can be used in conjunction with `IBuilderContext` Property `Policies` to accomplish what you need.

```
IBuilderContext context; //passed in 
InjectionMember member; //set by you

member.AddPolicies(fromType, toType, name, context.Policies);
```

Both `IBuilderContext` and `ExtensionContext` have the Policies property and should work (full disclosure, I've only done it with ExtensionContext), so you can put your logic in a BuilderStrategy or a UnityContainerExtension.

This extension will add `InterceptionBehavior<PerfCounterInterceptor>` to all registrations, based on `SomeLogic()`:

```
public class MyExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Registering += Registering;
    }

    private void Registering(object sender, RegisterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SomeLogic())
        {
            var member = new InterceptionBehavior<PerfCounterInterceptor>();
            member.AddPolicies(e.TypeFrom, e.TypeTo, e.Name, Context.Policies);
        }
    }

    private bool SomeLogic()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You simply call `container.AddExtension(new MyExtension())` and going forward your `PerfCounterInterceptor` behavior will be added to all registrations.

Edit: For clarification.  This extension would have to be added BEFORE your registrations.  If you really need to apply them after the registrations have been made, you'd probably have to loop through `container.Registrations`, and use the types and name from there, rather than using the `Registering` event.